# How to send int between 32bit and 64bit processors iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, game-center, gamekit

Pretty much the title, I send an int in a struct using Gamekit and on the receiving end the other device gets it. 
Between 64bit cpus (iPhone 5S and over) the number is received fine. But when a iPhone 5 gets it (32bit cpu) the int is received as 0. Whats the correct way?

I've tried sending as NSInteger and the results are the same.

I have to add I have this issue with u_int_32t: 
When devices connect, each device trades random numbers. These numbers determine which player starts, and I'm using u_int_32t for this, however, 32bit cpus still receive 0. For example:

I declare 
`uint32_t _ourRandomNumber;`

Then, `_ourRandomNumber = arc4random();`

And then the numbers are sent, in a struct like this.

```
typedef struct {
    Message message;
    uint32_t randomNumber;
} MessageRandomNumber;
```

Using a method like this:

```
- (void)sendRandomNumber{
    MessageRandomNumber message;
    message.message.messageType = kMessageTypeRandomNumber;
    message.randomNumber = _ourRandomNumber;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&message length:sizeof(MessageRandomNumber)];
    [self sendData:data];
}
```

When the 32 bit cpu receives it then in the receiving method:

```
Message *message = (Message*)[data bytes];
if (message->messageType == kMessageTypeRandomNumber) {
    MessageRandomNumber *messageRandomNumber = (MessageRandomNumber*)[data bytes];

    NSLog(@"Received random number:%d", messageRandomNumber->randomNumber);
```

The NSLog shows: Received random number:0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSInteger` is going to be 64-bit on a 64-bit platform and 32-bit on a 32-bit platform.  If you don't care about 64-bit precision, you could always use an `int32_t` (or a `u_int32_t` if you want unsigned) type  to explicitly just use a 32-bit value.  It is generally wise to be explicit about data lengths when sending values between devices, which is what these types exist for (there's `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t`, and `int64_t` and their unsigned counterparts).

It's also worth mentioning that you need to be concerned about the byte order of the values (assuming larger values than `int8_t` and `u_int8_t`) when sending values to arbitrary hardware.  If you're only working with iOS devices this isn't going to be an issue, however.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please look at the edited question if you spot why sending as u_int32_t, 0 is received on the other end.

Comment: What is `Message`?  What if you switch the order of `Message` and `u_int32_t` in the struct?

Comment: Message is another struct, that helps me know that what is received is a RandomNumber message.

Comment: What types does it contain?  If it also has values that are different lengths on different platforms then you might be interpreting the data after those values incorrectly.  Switch the order of `Message` and `randomNumber` in your struct declaration and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Also, as a sanity test, you could take the `NSData*` you end up with at the end of `sendRandomNumber` and on the same platform pass it through your method that reads the data to make sure it is actually a platform issue, and not some other issue.

Comment: Bingo, the problem was the Message struct, it contained a enum value (kMessageTypeRandomNumber) that was declared in an enum using NSIntegers, changed the enum type to int32_t and now 32bit devices receive the random number. Thanks for the help!